# Giving default values for columns in join condition in oracle SQL Query

Tags: sql, join, conditional-statements

I have 3 tables

**users(userid,UserName)**

```
1,Ram
2,Krishna
3,Madhu
4,Deepak
```

**roles(roleid,roleName)**

```
101,Agent
102,User
103,Manager
```

**user_role_map(userId,roleId)**

```
1,102
2,103
3,101
```

I need to get following details in my query. If there is no record in user_role_map for a user i need to get RoleName as NONE

**UserID, UserName, RoleName**

```
1,Ram,User
2,Krishna,Manager
4,Deepak,NONE
```

Below query is not returning UserID 4

```
SELECT  u.UserID
    ,   u.UserName
    ,   r.RoleName
FROM users u, roles r, user_role_map ur
WHERE u.UserID = ur.UserID
    AND r.roleid = ur.roleid
```

Comment: thats because UserId 4 not exists in user_role_map..

Comment: You should really state which database we are talking about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this - not tested but it looks right to me

```
select 
  u.UserID, u.UserName, IsNull(r.roleName, 'NONE') 
from 
  users u
  left join user_role_map ur on
    ur.UserId = u.UserId
  left join roles r on
    r.roleid=ur.roleid
```

Comment: I would recommend you familiarise yourself with the syntax of `JOIN` and `LEFT JOIN`.  Joins in the `WHERE` clause are old-fashioned.